# How to compile for older 3dsmax versions with 2010 \ 2011 sdk?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript, autodesk

I'm working on a plugin, and previously I saw that I could compile for several older versions of 3dsmax with just 2010 sdk installed.

The new project I've got works now with 32\64 max 2011 and 2010 (since they are compatible),
but how do I compile for the older versions?

How does one set up such a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compile using the .lib and .h files of older MaxSDK versions. Try looking for someplace where you can get them. But I dont know where...

Comment: I had one project, and just had 2010 SDK installed, but was still able to compile for 2008->2010 x32 and x64.
(this was set up in the project, one item for each 3dsmax in the dropdown where you select release\debug etc).

So I don't think I need "all" sdk's to compile, simply because I did not have them installed when I was compiling (and never had any other SDK then the 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. Have a look at header file ../maxsdk/include/plugapi.h

It contains version numbers for plenty of 3ds max releases.

Comment: That's just for histories sake. It will not allow you to target an older version of 3dsmax.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is you can't. Given an SDK of 3ds Max, it only allows you to target that version of the product. Unless the SDK is locked (A very bad thing.. trust me) then you do that. But even if the SDK is locked I don't suggest using the 2011 SDK to compile plugins for the 2010 product.